# Flutter `socket_io_client` convert socket.on(event, data) to stream and use in dynamically generated stream builder

Tags: sockets, flutter, dart, socket.io, stream-builder

I have a list of people, each with their own socket connection. I am using a `ListBuilder` to generate a list of widgets for them but I want each of these widgets to listen if the person's socket connection has received an event from the server and update accordingly. I have tried everything I could find online and still cannot find a solution to this.

This is what I have tried with one of the solutions posted below

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:socket_io_client/socket_io_client.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<Person> sockets = [
    Person(
        name: 'Jon',
        socket: io('http://localhost:3000', {
          'transports': ['websocket'],
          'autoConnect': false
        }),
        controller: StreamController<String>()),
    Person(
        name: 'Tim',
        socket: io('http://localhost:3000', {
          'transports': ['websocket'],
          'autoConnect': false
        }),
        controller: StreamController<String>()),
    Person(
        name: 'Bob',
        socket: io('http://localhost:3000', {
          'transports': ['websocket'],
          'autoConnect': false
        }),
        controller: StreamController<String>()),
  ];

// function to sink the data
  void sinkToController(data, Person person) {
    var message = '$data';
    person.controller.sink.add(message);
  }

  void streamPerson(Person person) {
    person.socket.connect();
    person.socket.on('connect', (data) {
      print('connected');
      person.socket.on('serverMessage', (data) {
        print('$data');
        sinkToController(data, person);
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Socket test app"),
      ),
      body: Container(
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 3,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                streamPerson(sockets[index]);

                return GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () => sockets[index].socket.emit('msg', 'this is me: ${sockets[index].name}'),
                  child: Container(
                    height: 300,
                    width: 350,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Text(sockets[index].name),
                        StreamBuilder<String>(
                          initialData: 'initial',
                          stream: sockets[index].controller.stream,
                          builder: (context, snapshot) {
                            return Text('${snapshot.data}');
                          },
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              })),
    );
  }
}

class Person {
  String name;
  Socket socket;
  StreamController<String> controller;

  Person({this.name, this.socket, this.controller});
}
```

However, this doesn't work so I was hoping if there was a way to convert the socket.on('event') to a stream dynamically and use it in the generated stream builder.

The result from this is

[image: A listBuilder where each person **should** have there own stream of data with their own name]

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should use a StreamController to create a stream per user. You can read more about it here: https://dart.dev/articles/libraries/creating-streams#using-a-streamcontroller

^^^Edited to add a better answer above

Below was my initial shot at this with generators. It probably won't work, though.

```
  Stream userToLocationStream(User user) async* {
    user.websocket.on('connect', (_) {
      user.websocket.on('LocationChange', (data) {
        yield data;
      });
    });
  }
```

Maybe if you decide to follow this generator route instead of StreamController, my talk that covers generators might be helpful: https://youtu.be/vPHxckiSmKY?t=4112

Answer (score 0):

```dart
// List of people to generate
var people = [
Person(name = 'Tina', email = 't@t.com', socket = IO.Socket('$host/events?userId=userID'))
Person(name = 'Bob', email = 'b@b.com', socket = IO.Socket('$host/events?userId=userID'))
Person(name = 'James', email = 'j@j.com', socket = IO.Socket('$host/events?userId=userID'))
];

//creating a controller for each
final _controllers = people.map((_) => StreamController<Message>()).toList();

//socketIO
user.websocket.on('connect', (_) {
    user.websocket.on('LocationChange', (data) {
        // NOTE: before sink convert data in to Message class
        sinkToController(data,user)
    });
});

// function to sink the data
void sinkToController(data,user){
   // create a helper function to convert json data to Message object
   var message = convertToMessage(data);
   _controllers[people.indexOf(user)].sink.add(message);
}
// listView builder will looks like this
ListView.builder(
    itemCount: people.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
      return  StreamBuilder<Message>(
          stream: _controllers[index],
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Message> snapshot) {
               // here you can play with your data now
               // var message = snapshot.data;
               // var user = people[index];
          });
    }
)
```

I Hope this is what you are looking for. This is not a better answer(practice). because I maintain 2 arrays to control the situation.I suggest you to create another wrapper class with user and the stream controller. and don't forget to close the connections after your work done.

for the example I used the json data as Message you have convert it into model class. You can convert `json` to dart model classes using this [vs code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hirantha.json-to-dart) easyly.

Comment: Where would I call the user.socket.on for each user. Would I create a function that has person as a parameter and then call it in the listview.builder?

Comment: I tried this solution however the data was not separated even with 3 streams. I have updated my code in the question.